# error Cannot delete property '2' of [object Array] using splice static method on my reducer NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I´m getting this error on console:

***TypeError: Cannot delete property '2' of [object Array] at Array.splice***

when I try to use static method splice over the array I passed on my reducer to update the store

Here how the store's property sideNavCustomGrids looks like on NgRx Store DevTools before I fire the removeSideNavCustomGrid action. It´s an array of objects

[image]

and here the structure of the action removeSideNavCustomGrid inside my reducer:

```
export const customDistributionsReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,

  on(CustomDistributionsActions.updateSideNavCustomGrid, (currentState, action: any): any => ({
    ...currentState,
    sideNavCustomGrids: [...action.list],
  })),

  on(CustomDistributionsActions.removeSideNavCustomGrid, (currentState, action: any): any => {
    const idIndex = action.list.findIndex((e:any) => e.id === action.id);
    action.list.splice(idIndex, 1);
    return {
        ...currentState,
        sideNavCustomGrids: [...action.list],
    }
  })
);
```

My investigations lead me to think that the error is related to the immutability of the NgRx store. I think your values are read only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both actions and store are usually readonly in development mode. it can be configured in StoreModule.forRoot(...) config.

to use splice you could create local array copy in your reducer and modify it as you want.

```
const list = [...action.list];
list.splice(idIndex, 1);
return {
    ...currentState,
    sideNavCustomGrids: list,
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, it works! Anyway, I would have expected to need a deep clone and not a shallow clone as at your example. As the value of sideNavCustomGrids (action.list into the reducer) its an array of objects and even each object has an array nested I would have expected to need a deep clone (JSON parse and stringify) instead of destructuring (shallow copy)

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly modify the array in the store since it has read only state, you can use short hand ES6 filter method to filter out the item which matches the id.

```
on(CustomDistributionsActions.removeSideNavCustomGrid, (currentState, action: any): any => {
const list = action.list.filter((e:any) => e.id !== action.id);

return {
    ...currentState,
    sideNavCustomGrids: [...list],
 }
})
```